# flutter on click open and collapse dropdown

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to do Collapsible in flutter, But Im not sure what is exactly need to write, I have below code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome to WesterAf'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      ),
      body: ExpansionTile(
        title: Text('Early Bird Registation'),
        // leading: Icon(Icons.local_pizza),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.expand_more),
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text('general registation'),
                  Text('yesllow'),
                  Text('mitukula vekatesh'),
                  new Radio(value: 0, groupValue: 23, onChanged: null),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Text('general registation'),
                  Text('yesllow'),
                  Text('venkey'),
                  new Radio(value: 0, groupValue: 23, onChanged: null),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Im getting the dropdown but I need more than 1,below image is what exactly I want looking.
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are building one ExpansionTile.

If you want multiple ExpansionTiles, use an [ExpansionPanelList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html).

It takes a list of ExpansionTiles as children and got an expansionCallback-function, where you can process, what should happen, if an ExpansionPanel is clicked.
For example set the state to open a panel:

```
expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
  setState(() {
    _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
  });
},
```

See the official documentation, there is an code-sample for that.

Comment: @Mitukula if this answer worked for your question, please consider marking this answer as correct